# referencing markdown mainpage content with doxygen 1.8.3

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I'm using a markdown mainpage (`mainpage.md`) like this

```
The Main Page
=============

qwertz

A Section
---------

asdf
```

together with `USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = mainpage.md` in the configuration.

I'd like to (auto-)link to the section 'A Section' from the documentation in the source coude, but I haven't yet figured out how to do that. I assume the 'A Section' generates an auto-linkable target, but how do I reference that (i.e. using `\see ?WhatToWriteHere?`)?

Additionaly, trying this

```
A Section {#asdfg}
---------
```

yields the strange warning `found subsection command outside of section context!`.

Comment: Seems like a doxygen bug. See [the other question][1], for a more in depth exploration. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648124/header-label-in-doxygen-markdown-page-makes-header-title-disappear

Comment: Ok, maybe I should move this over to the doxygen mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you code the mainpage using `@section section_01 A Section` instead of using the `=====` underlines then you can use the doxygen command

`@ref section_01 "text for link here"`

to create a link to it from elsewhere. I'm doing this successfully using 1.8.5.

It seems that vanilla markdown headers (either using underlining of # sequences) processed by Doxygen don't produce anything that Doxygen recognises as a target - either for linking to or for listing in a document index (which is a bit frustrating).